# Python 3 error: ImportError: No module named selenium

Tags: ios, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, terminal

I am coding on Sublime Text. I have selenium installed and I keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/dylansiegel/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/shirts')

#driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Quilted Plaid Zip Up Shirt').click()
```

I am continually getting this error when I try to build:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/dylansiegel/Desktop/bot.py", line 1, in 
    from selenium import webdriver

ImportError: No module named selenium

[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/dylansiegel/Desktop/bot.py"]

[dir: /Users/dylansiegel/Desktop]

[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public]

Comment: I'm not sure it was just part of the error code.

Comment: It says: `-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python: No such file or directory`

Comment: You probably have more than one Python installation and selenium is installed on one of them while Sublime tries to run the other.

Comment: How do I delete the other python installation(s)?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd want to check which version of python is being used from your terminal.

This command would return the path/version: `which python`

Then you'd want to add that into a shebang at the top of your script using `#!PATH python`, like `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Now try to run your script from the terminal again and it should work.

If it doesn't, then try to install selenium again using either:

`sudo pip3 install selenium` or `sudo pip install selenium`.

Comment: When I type this commands it does nothing or gives me an error. Using `sudo pip3 install selenium` I get this error code:

Comment: WARNING: The directory '/Users/dylansiegel/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/dylansiegel/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.7)

Comment: @DylanSiegel Does the linked question work for you? Hope you've gotten the solution.

Comment: I now deleted all of the files I was having trouble with: Python, selenium, and homebrew. I now reinstalled home-brew and python, but pip3 won't work. Using the command `easy_install pip` doesn't work either. I got an error code which you can see below:

Comment: error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-28346.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Comment: Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Comment: @DylanSiegel Could you make a new question for the pip3 problem you're having? I think that's an entirely different problem from this.

Comment: Yes I already did @Yuu I will @ you in the comments.